# MagicalRecord does not save new objects

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

I setup my MagicalRecord stack like so:

```
MagicalRecord.setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
moc.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

Now when I create and want to save my object, I get `success` of `false` but the returned `error` is `nil` too. Also the object still has a `temporaryID` set to `true`.

```
let product =  Product.MR_createEntity()!

MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (ctx) -> Void in
    product.timeStamp = NSDate()
    product.title = "Some title"
}) { (success, error) -> Void in

    if !success{
        // No success but error is nil

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this in the past with playing with MagicalRecord at first.

Once you've toyed with it, you need to delete the DerivedData folder corresponding to the App you're making (or in turn the whole derived data folder).. It'll run fine the first time, then after that it doesn't or runs like it did the first time.

The general DerivedData folder is at: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

delete that and it should be fine. Or another option is delete the folder which corresponds to the folder which your app was built in:

```
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-someRandomString`
i.e.
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ajhtkvwcttbnsulsdfdsfqr`
```

Finally if this is STILL playing havoc, then another place to look is the App Container (which is the sandbox container) and this lives in:

```
`~/Library/Containers/com.youridentifier.whatever.AppName`
```

When you delete this though ALL saved CoreData data will be lost, as along with preferences etc.. pertaining to that App.

Hope this helps...